# Convert ISO8601 duration to Object without using moment.js

Tags: javascript, iso8601

I'm having some difficulties converting an ISO8601 duration with Javascript.
What I'm trying to do is the following:

1. I'm having an ISO8601 duration like this: P3Y2W1DT25H5M
2. Now I want to convert this to an Object so I'm able to access the properties like duration.days, duration.years etc.
3. I have been trying moment.js, but it keeps converting 30 days to 1 month (which is not the same). Also 364 Days will be converted to 11 Months 30 Days, which is something I don't want. 364 Days should remain 364 Days. However, on the moment.js site it does work so perhaps my set-up is wrong. But that doesn't matter because:
4. Preferably I don't want to include moment.js on my site, only to do 2 conversions. Therefor I'm looking into doing this manually.

However, I'm not sure on how to start this/implement this. Any help would be appreciated. If you feel that my question could be improved, let me know.

Thanks and kind regards

Comment: You can always look how moment is doing it : https://github.com/moment/moment/blob/develop/src/lib/duration/create.js#L50

Comment: @GabrielBleu thank you that is a very good idea, I will try that and see if it will work.

Comment: @GabrielBleu That worked, thanks!